Statement to convert float time value into a real TIME column
Some old time data stored as float needs to be converted into time fields. So, given the table:
CREATE TABLE #T 
(
    TVALUE FLOAT(8), 
    EXPECTED_TVALUE TIME
);

INSERT INTO #T (TVALUE, EXPECTED_TVALUE) 
VALUES (0, null), 
       (9.474, '09:47:40'), 
       (11.3015, '11:30:15'), 
       (1.0, '01:00:00'), 
       (13, '13:00:00');


Is it possible to write a statement that for all these possible values the desired outcome is achieved?
I came up with some parts of it but none is valid or leads me to a correct working statement:
SELECT 
    TVALUE, EXPECTED_TVALUE, 
    FORMAT(FLOOR(TVALUE) * 10000 + (TVALUE - FLOOR(TVALUE)) * 60 + (TVALUE - FLOOR(TVALUE)) * 60, '00:00:00') AS TMP_TVALUE 
FROM #T

SELECT 
    TVALUE, EXPECTED_TVALUE, 
    CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(SECOND, TVALUE * 3600, 0),108) AS TIME) AS TMP_TVALUE 
FROM #T

SELECT 
    TVALUE, EXPECTED_TVALUE, 
    FORMAT(TVALUE, '00:00:00') AS TMP_TVALUE 
FROM #T

I'd rather not use functions or procedures since it must be part of a (much) larger migration script.
EDIT / DISCLAIMER
The given float type is historical data. Created some 20+ years ago. It's a given fact. My job is to converted it to a time type.

The first thing to recognize here is that that floating point is not an exact type.  There is no guarantee that what you see is what you would get as a string/time output in every case.  If you wanted to go this route, you should at least use an exact numerical type, such as decimal/numeric.

Something like: TRY_CAST(STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT(CONCAT(replicate('0', 6), CAST(TVALUE * 10000 AS INT)), 6), 5, 0,':'), 3, 0, ':') AS time) but yeah, not the best storage format me thinks

Why FLOAT(8) ? How many fractional digits do you expect? The choice of FLOAT was a design error, not a matter of age. The sysjobschedules table, which hasn't changed much since the 1990s, still uses int to store time as if it was a string, eg 1130 for 11:30:00 for the time. Without that error, you could use any of the many techniques available to convert 113015 into 11:30:15. Right now you have to accept that some of those times have changed due to precision problems

If the values were stored as integers you could use integer division to get the various digits and TIMEFROMPARTS to construct a time without going through string operations. With FLOAT you'll have to multiply by 10000 at least before you can get the digits

As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

First of all, you'll have to inspect all the stored values, or at least check for minimums, maximums and values above 24.0. Expecting 0 to map to NULL instead of 00:00:00 suggests there are more quirks than just loss of precision. There may be other magic values like this.
Even the sysjobschedules table that hasn't changed a lot since the 1990s uses int to store time as digits, eg 1154 for 11:54. Using FLOAT(8) was a matter of choice, not age. There may be a reason for this.
You can use some multiplication and modulo operations to extract the various digit pairs and use TIMEFROMPARTS to create a time value without string formatting.
The following query :
select * ,
    round(tvalue,0,1) as H,
    cast(round(tvalue*100,0,1) as int) % 100 as M,
    cast(round(tvalue*10000,0,1) as int) % 100 as S,
    timefromparts(
        round(tvalue,0,1),
        cast(round(tvalue*100,0,1) as int) % 100,
        cast(round(tvalue*10000,0,1) as int) % 100,0,0) as Time
from #t

Returns :
TVALUE  EXPECTED_TVALUE     H   M   S   Time
0       NULL                0   0   0   00:00:00
9.474   09:47:40.0000000    9   47  40  09:47:40
11.3015 11:30:15.0000000    11  30  15  11:30:15
1       01:00:00.0000000    1   0   0   01:00:00
13      13:00:00.0000000    13  0   0   13:00:00

The only difference is 0 and NULL. 00:00:00 is a perfectly valid time, not NULL.
You can use IIF(TValue=0, NULL, TIMEPART(...)) to convert 0 to null
